# Неточное совпадение символов при поиске MySql

Tags: mysql, search, like

Запрос `` select * from `table_name` where `value` like '%don%' `` возвращает запись, которая включает слово "Dönər". При том что **o** и  **ö** разные символы, mysql видит их как один и тот же. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: `collate` добавить какой нить ?

Comment: Да, проблема заключалась в этом. Спасибо.

Comment: опубликуйте более развернуто ответом.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо использовать collation имеющий параметр AS — Accent Sensitive, отвечающий за учет аксонов (диакритических знаков), тогда **o** не будет считается равным **ö**.